# How do I make a command to send the users profile picture in an embed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I want to make a command **!avatar @user** which will send the profile picture of the user, I am new to coding so if anyone can help me, I will highly appreciate that. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It is great that you are reaching out to Stack Overflow community for input. It is best to showcase your work to get help. Can you please post your code here so we can see what you have done so far.

Comment: should I just edit and add it to the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Is the command I personally use -

```
@client.command(aliases=['profilepic','pfp'])
async def avatar(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    member = ctx.author if not member else member
    embed = discord.Embed(color=0x40cc88, timestamp=ctx.message.created_at)
    embed.set_image(url=member.avatar_url)
    embed.set_footer(text=f"Requested by {ctx.author}")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

If there are any problems, please do comment.